# Detecting a Pi Bluetooth server on an IPhone

Tags: bluetooth, ios

I am trying to set up an IoT device using a Raspberry Pi 3A+. I want the Pi to connect to WiFi, so for this I set up an access point on which the WiFi credentials can be sent. The issue is finding this access point, as iOS does not allow scanning for available WiFi networks (bear in mind, this needs to work with multiple devices, so I cannot use a predetermined SSID).

I have tried to solve this using Bluetooth a Bluetooth server that has the name of the access point's SSID. While this works fine for Android, iOS devices are never able to detect the server. For setting up the Bluetooth server, I use the following:

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
[bluetoothctl]# serial-alias <ACCESS POINT SSID>
[bluetoothctl]# menu scan
[bluetoothctl]# transport le
[bluetoothctl]# back
[bluetoothctl]# discoverable on
```

In `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` I have set `DiscoverableTimeout = 900` and `ControllerMode = le`.

I hope someone can help me figure out how to setup the Bluetooth server properly. It only needs to be detectable and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising. I will try it out.

Comment: @ukBaz: Perhaps consider making your comment(s) an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of setting up a BlueZ GATT server at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server

You will also need to create an advertisement so that it can be discovered. There is an example advertisement in the BlueZ tree at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement

The documentation for the various APIs are at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc